# IE7 ignores display:table-row

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been working on a page where we hide a TR (table row) using `display:none` and later need to show it via `display:table-row`. However, IE7 ignores `table-row` and leaves the TR hidden. If I simply say `display:block`, all the cells are out of line with the columns. Any workarounds for this limitation?

Comment: Have you tried just letting it blank : tr.style.display = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` to toggle visibility of the element. 
Check this example at http://jsfiddle.net/JauH4/4/

Comment: As you may already have noticed though, there's a difference between visibility: hidden and display: none. Visibility only hides the element, but it will continue to affect the layout after it's been hidden, and thus you will have empty tablerows. I'm not saying "don't use", but "use where appropriate".

Comment: If you want to affect the layout you can use Jquery `show()` and  `hide()` or  the `toggle()`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because those methods toggle "display: none".

Comment: As far as I know they toggle between `dispaly:none` and `displya:block`. The use of `display:table-row` is different.I will add it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, it toggles between display: none and whatever the display value was before being set to "none".

Answer (score 6):

Just set display to "" when you want to show it again.

Edit: Here's a fiddle, observe how the display property is removed when we don't need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/V4xvX/

Try it with IE 7.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I'm adding a style block; how do you do the above in that? `display:;`?

Comment: Nope, i suppose you just remove the whole display-business, when it isn't "none".